# Is this statement true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Determine if the following statement is true or false and state a brief explanation.

The equation $Ax=b$ is consistent if and only of $b$ is a linear combination of the rows of $A$.

I said, false if and only if $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Can someone explain and tell me if it is correct?

-Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You're correct.  In general, $A$ might be of size $m$ by $n$ where $m \neq n$, in which case a linear combination of the rows of $A$ would be an $n$ element row vector while $b$ is an $n$ element column vector.

Comment: So, the statement is false?

Comment: Yes.  You are correct that the statement is false.